# Rails query based on User Timezone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, ransack

I need to query based on user timezone (EST), currently it is taking UTC. I've a date range filter by which the user selects a date range, according to that corresponding results are shown.

I'm using ransack gem for searching

Date range - 2016-03-01 to 2016-03-31

Results are shown in UTS, which shows as 29 Feb which should not appear

[image]

Form looks like

```
.well
  = simple_form_for(:report, url: report_create_path, method: :get, html: { class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f|
    = f.simple_fields_for(:q) do |r|
        = r.input :created_at_gteq, label: 'From', required: false, as: :bootstrap_datepicker
        = r.input :created_at_lteq, label: 'To', required: false, as: :bootstrap_datepicker
```

Do I need to use offset here or any default ransack default methods provides this feature?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used in my project. It didn't use the `ransack` gem and it used `MongoDB` instead of `postgresql`, but it should still work with your project:

```
start_date = DateTime.strptime(params[:created_at_gteq], "%m/%d/%Y").change(offset: Time.zone.formatted_offset).utc
end_date = DateTime.strptime(params[:created_at_lteq], "%m/%d/%Y").change(offset: Time.zone.formatted_offset).end_of_day.utc
```

Now, in my database, it always stores the `datetime` in UTC. Not sure if it does in your database. If it doesn't, then remove the `.utc` at the end of the lines to not convert it to UTC.